# How can I set the time in my Windows Phone 8 application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How can I set the device's system time in my Windows Phone 8 application, using C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to update the system date time then **You cannot set the "System DateTime" of your windows phone device**. The API is not exposed/supported by the SDK.

Comment: Then How to do it in kernel level of windows phone?

Comment: Your app will be sandboxed when it will run on phone.  You cannot do it at kernel level. Your app will be rejected in store if you add anything not approved by Microsoft.

Comment: I could not going to get approved by Microsoft. I want to use this app on 5 or 6 mobiles for our need.

Answer (score 0):

even if you developer unlock all the phones, or run it as a company app bypassing the store, you still can't change the system time. 
in apps where i require an accurate device time, if the network is available, i compare the device date/time with a server date/time via a web service method, and then if the time is out by more than some limit, block the user from continuing until they correct their device time.  Be aware of time zone issues if you are doing this.

Comment: I refer some articles about setting time they use SetSystemTime() functions. But It's not working for me. They use    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")] // for Windows CE/.NET CF use [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
        private extern static uint SetSystemTime(ref SYSTEMTIME lpSystemTime);

Comment: CE / Compact Framework belongs with Windows Mobile 5/6.  you are using a new platform and it has a new SDK.  read up on the windows phone SDK and forget all about COM and DllImports and PInvokes.